# How to access .sdf file from remote drive with SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-ce, lan

Currently I am working on .NET Desktop application which uses SQL Server Compact Edition. It works fine with single-local machine. Now I want to use database file which resides on another connected(connected by LAN) machine. I am able to map remote system's drive which contains database file. So what I need to do to access .sdf file from remote system.

Comment: And what have you tried? Any exceptions? Any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing SQL Server Compact (.sdf) files across a LAN is not supported, use SQL Server Express for multi-user / shared data scenarios.